# Threejs: can I show object boundingbox

Tags: javascript, debugging, three.js, ogre

I'm come from Ogre and C++, and now I'm developing with Threejs.

In ogre, for debug, I often use method:

```
Ogre::SceneNode* n = ...
n->showBoundingBox(true);
```

Just for debug and test.

Is there a similar method in Threejs? I'm using Sprite object.

Answer (score 0):

In r67 (latest release) there is BoundingBoxHelper function that will show the world-axis-aligned bounding box for an object.